# "Frequency Shift Keying" Decoder for Android

Tags: android, signal-processing

I'm trying to transfer some data through audio port of android device, I'm using FSK (Frequency Shift Keying) I'm using two different frequencies to represent 1 and 0.
Is there any android library or sample code to FSK decode captured audio data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out this

https://code.google.com/p/audio-analyzer-for-android/source/browse/README

General tips:

- Make sure to apply a window function.
- Select a sample frequency that makes the fft transform hit your two frequencies as close as possible with as few samples as possible.

Comment: I'm going through this analyser, its giving me FFT graph, But what I need is TFFT graph, I need to analyse frequency vs time graph.
Anyway this is a good place to start with. still I'm going through the API. If you have any other clue please comment. Thanks

Comment: Is it not enough to run the FFT faster than the nyquist frequency to differentiate between 0 and 1?

Comment: Only issue I have is once I get FFT data, how can i use FFT data to retrieve frequency data? I'm actually not a Electrical Engineer, I'm a software Engineer, so kind of out of touch with this theoretical stuff. Now I'm trying to use counting zero crossings method.